# make menuconfig error while trying to build kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I want to learn Linux Kernel and I've downloaded the latest kernel version. Now I want to configure Linux with `make menuconfig` and I'm receiving an error:

> Arch/x86/Makefile:184  Compiler lacks asm-goto support...

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Tell us about your development machine?

Answer (score 3):

Your trouble is relative to [this patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e501ce957a786ecd076ea0cfb10b114e6e4d0f40) [x86: Force asm-goto].

You need to install a gcc version >= 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is because the cache of Makefile was dirty.

You can try my solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52757221/2703937